# Examples of ancient maps that gave names based on a cardinal direction

Tags: ancient-history, cultural-history, maps

Years ago I read that civilizations had maps like that of the Herodotus, who was an ancient Greek historian. Said maps named lands or peoples according to cardinal directions, but without referring to them as a **continent** or an **ethnicity**. Besides the Herodotus maps, I only know of the below Chinese maps. Does anyone know of any other such maps?

To to clear, the person/civilization didn't actually have to draw maps necessarily. They only had to name  lands according to cardinal points. If I'm not mistaken, one of the societies that did that was the Persians.

[image: Chinese "Huaxia" map]

[image: Herodotus T and O map]

Comment: So you're asking what maps are known to have existed in the ancient world? What sort of scale are you considering (countrywide, continent-wide, global or something else) ?

Comment: Polynesian maps count as well? These are maps, but without text. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Islands_stick_chart

Comment: @stevebird Yes, but from a centrist perspective(ethnic or geographic). Continent-wide preferably(since they obviously did not know the whole world).

Comment: @santiago Yes, I think that counts. Thank you.

Comment: May I ask where you got that second map from? It reads, for North Europe, "Androphagi" -- men-eaters. That's... enough to make me curious. ;-)

Comment: @devsolar Wow I did not know that, I just typed "herodotus map" on google images and picked the first one.

Comment: This may be of interest https://blog.education.nationalgeographic.org/2016/04/08/aboriginal-songlines-helped-draw-the-map-in-australia/

Comment: Does "oriental" count? What about the names of the North Sea and Baltic Sea? What about Morocco?

Answer (score 1):

Some maps probably just did not survive to our time. For example, Pacific islanders
certainly had some sort of maps (they sailed long distance between the islands, this is impossible without some maps or substitutes.) Cook actually describes these maps
in his log. They were made of sticks. But none of them survived, and Cook's description is not sufficient to
reproduce them.

Remark. When the British discovered Pacific islands, they prohibited any travel between them except in the British ships. This led to to massive loss of knowledge:
we can only guess their methods of navigation and shipbuilding. All that remains is
Cook's and his contemporaries pictures and descriptions. The islanders had no writing while the British were not very interested in the native science.

Comment: You might be interested in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Islands_stick_chart

Comment: @Jan: Thanks for finding the picture. I've seen them in the books, but not on Internet.